# React native: Installing app-debug.apk

Tags: android, react-native

How do I create an APK installer for mobile without the react native simulator? This is what happened when I tried to install the APK on Android.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a key to sign the apk. Use below to create your key.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-app-key.keystore -alias my-app-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

then run following command one by ome

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \
  --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease


adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

While your packager is runnning, run this to create offline bundle

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

(You may need to create assets folder manually) 
This will create an offline bundle file and if you then run:

```
react-native run-android
```

It should deploy it your device.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of development version You should build and install production version of app.

For this you should Generating a signing key.

How to Generating Signed APK: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Then every time you want to generate a production version of app run this commands at project root directory.

RN < 0.40

`react-native run-android --variant=release`

RN >= 0.40

`react-native run-android --configuration=release`

then just run `adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`
or copy and past `app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk` file on you android and install it directly.